# Native syntax highlighting with Redactor

Tags: redactor

I would like my Redactor's content to include some code snippets but I don't know where to start. I just switched to CraftCMS from WordPress.

My intuition says that there should be a way to add a custom button to Redactor that wraps the selected content with custom tags (like `<pre><code>`) and then use a highlighter like for example [prism](https://prismjs.com/), but I don't know if that is the Craft way to do it.

The closest I've found is [fomattingAdd](https://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/settings/formatting/#s-formattingadd), but this doesn't allow me to create a format with multiple tags, like: `<pre><code> ... </code></pre>`

It would allow one single wrapper:

```
"formattingAdd": {
 "my-code": {
 "title": "Just code",
 "api": "module.block.format",
 "args": {
   "tag": "code",
   "class": "language-php"
 }
},
```

How can I achieve multiple wrapper tags for one single format? Do you know a better way to get this done?

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, but I would guess that many Craft devs would implement this as a dedicated block type in a "body builder" matrix, rather than mixing the content directly into an existing Redactor field. I'm not suggesting that this is necessarily a "better" way - there are pros and cons either way - just putting it out there in case it's a valid option for you.

Comment: @JamesSmith Thanks for your kind input. Makes total sense. But in this channel, probably not even a 5% of entries will include code snippets, only a few ones. Your solution seems a perfect fit for a development blog with tutorials where code snippets play a fundamental role, to have cleaner control of the body content. But in this case I prefer a code block inside Redactor, if that's possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this using the [Clips plugin](https://imperavi.com/redactor/plugins/clips/) with the following config:

```json
"plugins": ["clips"],
"clips": [
    ["PHP code", "<pre><code class=\"language-php\">Type here</code></pre>"]
],
```

This would insert what you need then highlight *Type here* and add your code!